# Unable to use socket.io in Typescript

Tags: socket.io, typescript

I downloaded the socket.io package typescript definition from:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/socket.io

However, the definition provided here does not work with the client side. I need to know what modification can be done to this file to ensure it works in in the client side - which also uses jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the given `Socket` interface manually:

```
var socket:Socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
```

Comment: There's no "io" variable and "connect" function defined in the socket.io.d.ts https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io/socket.io.d.ts. Do you know if this definition is wrong OR if there is another one?

Comment: Sorry. I just added it : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io/socket.io.d.ts#L68

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful of you. However, there still seems to be some problem on the server side for which I've posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652812/socket-io-typescript-definition-seems-incorrect - Maybe you could separate the client and server files in Github! Thanks again.