# Socket.io typescript definition seems incorrect

Tags: socket.io, typescript

I'm trying to test this code shown in the socket.io site, in my typescript project, but the Typescript definition doesn't seem to have the interfaces called in this function:

Here's my code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Here's the error:

```
error TS2094: The property 'sockets' does not exist on value of type '{ listen: { (server: http.Server, options: any, fn: Function): SocketManager; (server: http.Server, fn?: Function): SocketManager; (port: Number): SocketManager; }; }'.
```

Here's the d.ts file:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io/socket.io.d.ts#L68

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the socket.io API [changed between 0.6 and 0.7](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7+) and the declaration file hasn't been updated to reflect that.  So you're not doing anything wrong.

Most declaration files are maintained by volunteers independent of the project they describe.  If you could write a new declaration file and submit it to the definitelytyped project that would be appreciated.  I still think [this](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/) is the best guide on the process so far.

Comment: Its nice to know that.. Though I'm new to Typescript.. and definition files - so I'm tweaking my way around. But if I get one running without errors fora while - I'll probably upload it.

Comment: @EternallyCurious the files were just updated 8 hours ago (3 after your post). Might want to try getting the latest and seeing if it works, if not, create an Issue (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues) and hopefully someone will update it for you :)